# Как исправить ошибку ClassCastException, когда я пытаюсь валидировать ввод текста в jsf

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, classcastexception

Я написал метод валидатор

```
 public void validateCorseCode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
  throws ValidatorException {
if(value == null) {
  return;
}
String data = value.toString();
//CourseCode must start with LUV
if(!data.startsWith("My")) {
  FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("CourseCode must start with LUV");
  throw new ValidatorException(message);
}
```

}

Проверка на первые три буквы, которые ввел пользователь.
Проверка происходит на jsf страницы вот код:

```
<h:inputText value="#{studentValidFour.courseCode}" label="Course code" id="courseCode" required="true"
                                validator="#studentValidFour.validateCorseCode}" >
  </h:inputText>
```

Ошибка возникает именно в этом месте в методе :

```
if(!data.startsWith("My")) {
  FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("CourseCode must start with LUV");
  throw new ValidatorException(message);
}
```

Если убираю `throw new ValidatorException`, все работает.

Код следующий:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   javax.faces.application.FacesMessage cannot be cast to class
>   java.lang.String (javax.faces.application.FacesMessage is in unnamed
>   module of loader 'javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02' @3983b87e;
>   java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Код рабочий, если вернуть потерянный символ `{` в выражении `validator="#...`. Если вводить строку, начинающуюся не с "My" то на страницу выводится ошибка валидации _CourseCode must start with LUV_ (при условии того, что на странице есть компонент отображения ошибок, например - `h:message`). Есть вероятность того, что у Вас какие-то проблемы с конфигурацией/компиляцией/деплоем приложения. Такие проблемы нелегко разобрать в формате вопросов/ответов. Попробуйте развернуть минимально рабочее приложение с только одной страницей и проверить в нём.